# can we use object as a array or dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

```
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
           context.Response.Write(reader["timestamp"]);
    }
    reader.Close()
```

here we see, the reader is a SqlDataReader Object, but we use it as an array below,how it convert?

Answer (score 4):

You are not using `reader` as an array, you are using its [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the data for the column called "timestamp".

The indexer returns an object, which you can then cast to the appropriate type.

Alternatively, you can use more specific methods like [reader.GetSqlDateTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx), which return a specific, appropriate type.